# Open XML Export datatable to excel directly on disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, openxml

I want to export datatable to xlsx directly to my disk instead of giving destination path and saving file on server.

I have following function :

```
private void ExportToCSVFileOpenXML(DataTable dt, string destination)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtCopy = new DataTable();
        dtCopy = dt.Copy();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy);
        try 
        {


            var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Server.MapPath("~/" + destination.Replace("/","").Replace(":","")), DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            {           

                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

                foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {

                    var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                    sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                    string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                    uint sheetId = 1;
                    if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        sheetId =
                            sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                    }

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
                    sheets.Append(sheet);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    {
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }


                    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                        foreach (String col in columns)
                        {
                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }

                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                    }

                }
            }



                }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

How can I directly export this to disk instead of saving on server by giving destination path as :

```
var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Server.MapPath("~/" + destination.Replace("/","").Replace(":","")), DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpreadsheetDocument.Create accepts a stream, string, or package as its first argument so we can just use a MemoryStream to create the workbook in memory and return a byte array.

It should be something like this:

```
public byte[] ExportToCSVFileOpenXML(DataTable dt)
    {
        byte[] returnBytes = null;
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            // your code

            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();

            returnBytes = mem.ToArray();
        }

        return returnBytes;
    }
```

Once you have a byte array passing it as a file should be quite easy.

If you are using MVC it should be something like this in your controler:

```
return File(ExportToCSVFileOpenXML(aTable), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "export.xlsx");
```

Comment: your answer lead me to correct answer as i mentioned below. Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Alex answer lead me to correct answer.

I did following thing :

```
private byte[] ExportToCSVFileOpenXML(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtCopy = new DataTable();
        dtCopy = dt.Copy();
        ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy);
        try 
        {
            byte[] returnBytes = null;
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();
                foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                    sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                    string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                    uint sheetId = 1;
                    if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        sheetId =
                            sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                    }

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
                    sheets.Append(sheet);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    {
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }


                    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                        foreach (String col in columns)
                        {
                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }

                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                    }

                }
            }
            workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();

            returnBytes = mem.ToArray();

            return returnBytes;
                }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Called this function as:

```
protected void hlInCorrectRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "";
        DataSet dsDtUploadedSummary = (DataSet)ViewState["dsDtUploadedSummary"];
        if (dsDtUploadedSummary.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable dtFreshRecords = dsDtUploadedSummary.Tables[4];
            if (dtFreshRecords.Rows.Count > 0 && dtFreshRecords != null)
            {                
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                string filename = @"IncorrectRecordsUploaded_" + DateTime.Now.ToString();                
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename.Replace("/", "").Replace(":", "")+".xlsx");
                Response.BinaryWrite(ExportToCSVFileOpenXML(dtFreshRecords));                                
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = "No Data To Export";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "No Data To Export";
        }
    }
```

Thanks Alex. I am using plain ASP.NET not MVC

Comment: Glad you got it working, It would be a very good idea to use a using statement like in my example as it will make sure the memorystream is correcntly disposed off in a timely mannor. Its not the sort of thing you want lingering around.

Comment: @Alex yeah i removed it because each time when exception was comming, i  had to restart the program execution, instead, now with try can i can drag the execution with debugger from catch to try again

Comment: @Alex above code is creating me problem when there are 1k records , its throwing timeout exception

Comment: its not exactly something you want to be doing on a per request basis if its going to take so long that you hit a HTTP timeout, you could use some fancy javascript to run the proccess asynchronously and polling to find out when its done and only then serving the data.  Or you can work out whats taking so long and make it faster or you could split the data into smaller chunks.

Comment: @Alex I didnt understood your javascript side hadling option.. what should i do in javascript ? how can i do that ? is there any link ?